# RegEx to Delete left & right tag data and leave text in between intact

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm using NotePad++ version 6.1.2. Is it possible to get a RegEx to delete data from the left and from the right and leave the data in between intact?  Below is a small example to go by:

`<data_1 to be deleted><data_2 to be deleted>Data I need to remain intact</data I need deleted?>`

So to clarify, everthing located at the left including the most outer left and right `< >` symbols need to be deleted (this is tricky due to the `><` symbols in between confusing the operation).

Then the text within the `>` and the `</` symbol needs to remain intact.

Lastly, the data located to the right needs to be deleted including the `</` and `?>` symbols.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to delete everything in <>? Meaning \<.*\>

Comment: @chill0r -- The `.*` is greedy and would take away too much.  Better would be `<[^>]+>` (Not sure if Notepad++ requires escaping the `<` and `>`)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   <[^\/]+>(.+?)<\/[^>]+>
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wD9jC3).

Answer (score 0):

Using Search & Replace with regex enabled (ctrl+H or search -> replace):

Find: `<[^<>]*>`

Replace: (Leave blank.)

This will find any tag starting with `<` and ending with `>` (including ending tags like `</ending_tag>`, and replace them with nothing, therefor removing them.

`<data_1 to be deleted><data_2 to be deleted>Data I need to remain intact</data I need deleted?>` is converted to `Data I need to remain intact`.

**Note**: In cases of malformed tags, this will take the smallest possible tag:

`<formula>19 + x < 5</formula>` converts to `19 + x < 5`.

`<formula>300 > 200</formula>` converts to `300 > 200`.